# Entity Code first - required decimal

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using the modelBuilder class. Setting a not null field is easy using IsRequired when the property is of type string. As soon as the type is of type decimal, intellisense is not showing the IsRequired method.

```
  public class CategotyConfig: EntityConfiguration<Category>
  {
        public CategotyConfig()
        {
            this.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();
        }
  }
```

How can I set a field of type decimal to be not null ? Without using attributes.

Comment: +1 for asking a different question than the one I had, but getting an answer that helped me figure out my solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` (as opposed to `decimal?`) is already required, because it's non-nullable.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is simple :-)